# BS Datepicker Format Date Before Sending it to Firebase

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

In my Angular component I have a date of birth field where I am using bs date picker. When I am selecting a date from the datepicker and submitting the form it send the date in this format `3 October 1991 at 18:30:00 UTC+5:30` to Firebase. on Component onInIt when I am getting the date from server and using patch value, the value in the date of birth field says Invalid Date. Is there any way that i format the date before sending it to the server? i am using reactive forms and using the date picker in the below format -

```
<input
  type="email"
  placeholder="Enter Date Of Birth"
  class="from-input-profile"
  formControlName="dob"
  bsDatepicker
  [bsConfig]="{ 
     adaptivePosition: true
  }"
/>
```

Comment: do you have a service that sends the data to firebase? are you unable to format this date value in this service prior to saving it?

Comment: yes I do have a service..No I tried to format that but that didnt work. Can you please share any code for formatting the date.

Comment: the sample value you provided "3 October 1991 at 18:30:00 UTC+5:30" doesn't look like a valid date. there shouldn't be an "at" a value of type "date". but doing a quick search of ngx-bootstrap date picker -> https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker. you can see that you the option of configuring the data format that is returned from the datepicker. this needs to be set in the [bsconfig] property. for example: [bsConfig]="{ dateInputFormat: 'YYYY-MM-DD' }"
I would suggest using this to specify the format you want.

Comment: After using dateInputFormat: 'Do MMMM YYYY' from their documentation still it saves data in firestore as a timestamp.